# How is a reputation dropping from 4k to near zero and then a rising to 5k explained?

Tags: discussion

I came across a user*, which has a very strange reputation history.

Basically he asked a question how to round a number. I started wondering, how anyone with 39 gold badges and 5,9k rep was able to ask such a simple duplicate and looked at the profile:

[image: The user]

I am not sure, how this reputation graph could be explained? Is this a indication of a voting ring?

<sub>*URL by moderator request</sub>

Comment: Throw a flag on this post with the URL.

Comment: Well you could check his reputation history yourself instead of asking others to do that for you ...

Comment: @Undo done [...]

Comment: Did you try looking at their bounties tab?

Comment: "I started wondering, how anyone with 39 gold badges and 5,9k rep was able to ask such a simple duplicate" A user with **39 gold badges** for only 5.9k rep is one who asks questions rather than answering them. Typically the kind of user who asks as a first resort rather than a last, hence the large number of questions (and therefore large number of obvious duplicates). The vast majority of the gold badges owned by such a user are Famous Question and Stellar Question badges.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why was this downvoted so heavily? I found it interesting.

Comment: @SandPiper Would it also be interessting for you if the question would be: Go to page X and tell me what it says, because I couldn't be bothered to go myself? If not, then I wonder why, because this question is exactly that.

Comment: I'm not following, @tom. It is a situation I have never seen before. I'm glad you have been around long enough to spot the answer so quickly, but not everyone else has.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That'd be due to [a whole bunch of bounties](//stackoverflow.com/users/975566/samantha-j?tab=bounties&sort=offered) in that timeframe. No foul play here.

Comment: Ah, wasn't aware about that :(

Comment: That's also visible in the rep history: https://stackoverflow.com/users/975566/samantha-j?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=17